# Vertical Carousel with AnythingSlider

Tags: carousel, anythingslider

Im trying to set a vertical carousel with AnythingSlider. But, I need to set a fix width for UL, and the script dont allow this.  Is that possible?

[image: Carousel]

```
Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/5230/
```

But the list stay with a blank space ;/

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnythingSlider isn't, at this time, set up to allow multiple vertical slides. So, you will see some blank space below the last slide until it reaches the top.

To fix your demo, change this bit of css ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/5243/)):

```
ul#slider img  {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mottie. I will report this issue to developer at GitHub. Maybe he could find some way to fix it. What do you suggest? I'm thinking to use jCarousel...

Comment: LOL @Brightweb, I am the developer ;) I think I can fix it for basic functionality, I am having trouble making it work when the `expand` option is `true`... maybe I should just disable the expand option when  showing multiple slides in vertical mode until I solve it.

Comment: hahaha @Mottie I just realized that later. ^^ Ok, thanks. I appreciate your attention. Hugs!

Comment: Do you have any predictions for the fix?

Comment: Sorry, no, it's been a crazy week... I'm going to a funeral tomorrow... so we'll just have to see.

Comment: I'm sorry. My condolences. Get better!

Comment: As an incentive, I promise to make a donation if you fix it. haha ;D